# Ember.js: The metamorph tags have different parents

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm following a video tutorial for Ember.js and there's this one bit of a template that's throwing an error for me.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="repositories">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        {{#each}}<tr><td>{{name}}</td></tr>{{/each}}
    </table>
</script>
```

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The metamorph tags,
>   metamorph-27-start and metamorph-27-end, have different parents. The
>   browser has fixed your template to output valid HTML (for example,
>   check that you have properly closed all tags and have
>   used......')

Being new to ember, I don't have the foggiest what this means. So I've played with some versions of this to see what works.

Errors

```
{{#each}}<tr><td>test</td></tr>{{/each}}

{{#each}}<tr>test</tr>{{/each}}

{{#each}}<td>test</td>{{/each}}
```

Works

```
{{#each}}test{{/each}}

{{#each}}{{name}}{{/each}}

{{#each}}<li>test</li>{{/each}}

{{#each}}<li><span>test</span></li>{{/each}}

<tr>{{#each}}<td>{{name}}</td>{{/each}}</tr>
```

I've copied this from a great training video on Pluralsight (Ember.js Fundamentals by Rob Conery). It appears to work for him so, either I've copied something wrong or the framework has changed in the later version I'm running.

Hoping someone can help on this. Thanks

**UPDATE**

I'm running against the debug version of ember. The line that's breaking is

```
Ember.assert = function(desc, test) {
  if (!test) {
    throw new Ember.Error("Assertion Failed: " + desc);
  }
};
```

and the test itself

```
function _addMetamorphCheck() {
  Ember.Handlebars.EachView.reopen({
    _checkMetamorph: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {
      Ember.assert("The metamorph tags, " +
                   this.morph.start + " and " + this.morph.end +
                   ", have different parents.\nThe browser has fixed your template to output valid HTML (for example, check that you have properly closed all tags and have used a TBODY tag when creating a table with '{{#each}}')",
        document.getElementById( this.morph.start ).parentNode ===
        document.getElementById( this.morph.end ).parentNode
      );
    })
  });
}
```

The comment for this goes on to say:

> Ember build tools will remove any calls to `Ember.assert()` when doing
>   a production build.

So this might not be a problem in non debug files.. but it still doesn't account for the test failing on this, unless the test itself is bad?

Comment: haven't searched the reason for this, however it looks ok if you wrap contents in `tbody` http://emberjs.jsbin.com/povovudo/1/edit . Also the thing is that if you don't place a `tbody`, `hbs` will enter one for you and maybe it is related to the error.

Comment: @melc that's bang on the mark! whether or not it's hbs or the browser that's wrapping the tbody, this has fixed it. if you post as an actual answer then I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: great just posted it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks ok if the contents are wrapped inside a `tbody` element,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/povovudo/1/edit

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    {{#each}}<tr><td>{{name}}</td></tr>{{/each}}
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>
```

If a `tbody` element is not placed, then `hbs` seems to enter one automatically and maybe it is related to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Longshot here - maybe try your code on separate lines?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="repositories">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    {{#each}}
      <tr><td>{{name}}</td></tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</script>
```

This shouldn't be a problem, but basically the metamorph thing is Ember/Handlebars way of binding/change tracking and it needs to see individual elements.

Comment: Afraid that doesn't fix it either. I did start with nice formatting in there. Removing the whitespace and newlines was the first thing i tired, so I can understand you suggesting that too.